# How to stretch the table height in pdfmake?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfmake

Is there any option in `pdfmake` to fill the table in entire page ?

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/t2dbcb4t/

[image]

```js
var docDefinition = {
  pageMargins: [0, 0, 30, 0],
  content: [{
    table: {
      widths: ['20%', '80%'],
      body: [
        [{
            fillColor: '#ebebeb',
            color: '#000',
            text: 'first column',
          },
          [{
            fontSize: 24,
            fillColor: '#fff',
            text: 'My name'
          }, {
            margin: [-5, 0, 0, 0],
            table: {
              widths: ['120'],
              body: [
                [{
                  fontSize: 11,
                  bold: true,
                  fillColor: '#ebebeb',
                  margin: [15, 3, 0, 3],
                  text: 'PROFILE'
                }]
              ]
            },
            layout: 'noBorders'
          }, {
            text: [
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque aliquid, possimus officiis. Est, cum. Rem hic quisquam laborum ex quae nemo. Optio quam ad eaque obcaecati repellat pariatur nobis blanditiis. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In explicabo, velit dolorum sint. Error ea cum voluptatem quisquam, doloribus doloremque, maiores pariatur totam tempora cumque quo eos sint. Libero, aut! \n\n',
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat cumque unde quam ullam nostrum maxime laborum, labore aperiam? Neque, totam itaque recusandae excepturi explicabo sunt et culpa dolorem ea soluta! ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda dolorem totam iure quod ipsam in harum. Pariatur exercitationem quas maiores facilis labore ab, repudiandae voluptatum quia, delectus quidem debitis dolores! \n'
            ],
            style: ['summaryStyle']
          }]
        ]
      ]
    },
    layout: 'noBorders'
  }],
  styles: {
    summaryStyle: {
      fontSize: 10,
      alignment: 'justify',
      margin: [10, 10, 0, 10],
    },
    titleStyle: {
      bold: true,
      margin: [0, 0, 0, -2]
    },
    experienceStyle: {
      margin: [0, 0, 0, 10]
    }
  },
  defaultStyle: {
    color: '#000'
  }
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to set the height of the outer table to be the same as the page height. The first column with the gray background would "stretch" to the bottom while the content of the second column would remain where it is.